# Где происходит вызов метода run()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Начал работать в Eclipse, хочу посмотреть исходный код метода start() класса Thread, а именно понять как в нем организуется вызов метода run(). Написал в эклипсе некоторый код, жму клавишу Ctrl, навожу курсор на `thread.start()`, всплывает окошко, в котором можно выбрать выбрать Open Declaration или Open Implementation. Кликаю Declaration, открывает:

```
public synchronized void start() {
        /**
         * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
         * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
         * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
         *
         * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
         */
        if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();

        /* Notify the group that this thread is about to be started
         * so that it can be added to the group's list of threads
         * and the group's unstarted count can be decremented. */
        group.add(this);

        boolean started = false;
        try {
            start0();
            started = true;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (!started) {
                    group.threadStartFailed(this);
                }
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                /* do nothing. If start0 threw a Throwable then
                  it will be passed up the call stack */
            }
        }
    }
```

Я не понимаю как из этого кода может быть вызван метод run().

Comment: Вот здесь `start0();`

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) к методу start

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread...

явно написано, что метод `run` вызовет сама JVM ( и произойдет это внутри нативного метода `start0`)